# Oracle nested cursor with for loop

Tags: oracle

I am trying to make this work but no matter what I do the od_total var is always empty. I just cannot make it work.

I am trying to run a cursor to get a list of ordersid and save it into o_id every loop. Then, I use the second cursor to use the value stored into o_id to do another query that stores the result into od_total. While o_id seems to be storing the values, od_total for some reason is always empty.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_practicum2_practice IS
        o_id CHAR(5);
        od_total NUMBER := 0;
    CURSOR ordersid IS
        SELECT DISTINCT orderdetails.orderid FROM orderdetails 
        INNER JOIN orders ON orderdetails.orderid = orders.orderid 
        INNER JOIN customers ON orders.customerid = customers.customerid
        WHERE orders.customerid = 'LILAS';
    CURSOR total IS
        SELECT SUM(unitprice*quantity) FROM orderdetails WHERE orderid = o_id;
    BEGIN
        OPEN ordersid;
        OPEN total;
        LOOP
            FETCH ordersid INTO o_id;
                EXIT WHEN ordersid%notfound;
                  LOOP
                    FETCH total INTO od_total;
                        EXIT WHEN total%notfound;
                  END LOOP;
                  dbms_output.put_line(o_id || ' ----  ' || od_total);
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE ordersid;    
        CLOSE total;   
   END;
```

this is what I get as result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL3ZG.png)

Comment: Please read [ask] and post a [mcve]. "cannot make it work" is not a very helpful description.   Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I made some changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far i could understand your question you wanted to display  `od_total` for all `od_id` passed from cursor `ordersid`. You are not getting anything because `od_id` is not getting passed to your second cursor. Read the code below inline comments how to pass the argument to cursor.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_practicum2_practice
IS
  o_id     CHAR(5);
  od_total NUMBER := 0;
  CURSOR ordersid
  IS
    SELECT DISTINCT orderdetails.orderid
    FROM orderdetails
    INNER JOIN orders
    ON orderdetails.orderid = orders.orderid
    INNER JOIN customers
    ON orders.customerid    = customers.customerid
    WHERE orders.customerid = 'LILAS';

  CURSOR total(v_oid char)
  IS
    SELECT SUM(unitprice*quantity) 
    FROM orderdetails 
    WHERE orderid = v_oid;

BEGIN
  OPEN ordersid;  
  LOOP
    FETCH ordersid INTO o_id;
    EXIT WHEN ordersid%notfound;

    OPEN total(o_id); --<--This is how you pass the paramater to your cursor    
    LOOP
      FETCH total INTO od_total;
      EXIT  WHEN total%notfound;
      dbms_output.put_line(o_id || ' ----  ' || od_total);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE total;
    --If you print here then only the last od_total value will be printed.
    --dbms_output.put_line(o_id || ' ----  ' || od_total);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE ordersid;
END;
```

Output:

```
17465 ----  6
12345 ----  3
14435 ----  4
19045 ----  6
19345 ----  8
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. I tried to do as you suggested but did not work. Now I get the error "ORA-06511: PL/SQL: cursor already open". I got this error before that is why I was trying to open it just after the first cursor.

Comment: The `CLOSE total;` needs to be inside the outer loop to prevent the error @bryan is encountering.  I've edited the above code to make this fix.  Also, parameterized cursors are not strictly required, but are definitely cleaner.

Comment: @bryan See the working version of code above. Thanks Sentinel for fixing the code.

Comment: Working perfectly now. Thank you!